# How to send traidtional GA event in GTM's custom HTML tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm using GTM in my company's online shop, and I installed some other tag via GTM's custom HTML tag, like this:

```
<script>
//some JS code...

var customParam=[{"key":"value"}];
var jsElm=document.createElement("script");
jsElm.type="text/javascript";
jsElm.async=true;
jsElm.src="https://some_tags.com/tag.js?s=CV";
document.body.appendChild(jsElm);

if(today < some date)
{
  SEND GA EVENT here.....
}
</script>
```

The traditional GA event script

```
ga('send', 'event', 'XXX', 'pageview', 'some description', 1);
```

isn't working anymore here.

How do I did this ?

And I heard someone said that I should put data into DataLayer and do some bla bla bla... but I was understanding that too few to try. Is that a right way ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer with another question. Why are you sending events through HTML tags instead of Google Analytics Tag that are build just for that purpose?

I ll work with the assumption that you are new with this tool but the idea is that GTM replaces all old GA code on site. 
Just create a new Tag and select 'Universal Analytics' and after that you can choose which kind of information you want on Google Analytics.

[image]

Its pretty self explanatory as a tool so i strongly recommend you to forget about those old GA codes and work with what you got.

In addition to this have in mind that you can use custom javascript variables to scrap DOM values in case you need to.

Here is our guru Simo Ahava: https://www.simoahava.com/

If you need anything else just ask.

Comment: What I would like to do is putting a 3rd party tag which isn't directly support bu GTM (so I need to implement with custom HTML). I had to put it in thank you page, but will not fire this tag every time, only fire it when user purchased some of special goods. And I hope I can also send it to GA when it fired, so that drive me to ask a traditional GA way in GTM.

Comment: Just set the 3rd party tag and generate a special trigger for this goods or set up a lisener on the 3rd party HTML that fires de hit to GTM. Either way you can avoid old GA code. https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/add-load-listener-script-elements/ https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-custom-event-listeners-gtm/